# youtube_player_flutterを使用したiOSアプリが却下される

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, youtube, appstore-approval

flutterでyoutube動画を再生するアプリを作成して審査に提出したのですが、以下の理由で却下されました。作成したアプリは動画を再生する機能しかないのですが、却下されてしまいました。理由または修正方法がわかる方はぜひ教えてください。

[追記]8/13
別のライブラリを使用して、youtube公式のAPI使ってるよってレビューの情報に追記したら審査通りました。ご回答ありがとうございました。

> Guideline 5.2.3 - Legal
>
> We found your app provides potentially unauthorized access to third-party audio or video streaming.
>
> Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of another party. In the event your app infringes another party’s rights, you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App Review Information section in App Store Connect evidencing that you have all necessary rights or permissions to the third-party audio or video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services in your app.
>
> In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and the removal of your apps from the App Store. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.

Comment: 「わからない」とは英語がわからないということですか？それとも指摘の通り「ライセンス周りがわからない」ということですか？

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問(と回答) - [Is it allowed to play a youtube video within a Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59904678)

Comment: おそらく対応する日本語のページ [App Store Reviewガイドライン](https://developer.apple.com/jp/app-store/review/guidelines/) あなたのアプリでYouTube動画を再生する許可をYouTubeから受けていると証明できれば通るのかもしれません。

Comment: ライセンス周りです。サードパーティのライブラリを使用した場合Youtubeの動画は再生するだけでもだめみたいですね。

Comment: @cubick 
こちらの回答者も同じ理由で却下されていて未解決みたいですね

Comment: 「サードパーティ」は「ライブラリ」ではなくコンテンツ「audio or video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services」に掛かっていると思いますよ。

Comment: https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/485
なるほど。ここでも同じようなことが議論されていますね。
許可を得た動画のみの再生しかできないんですかね。

Comment: 解決に至った情報は質問文に含めてしまうのではなく、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してください。

Answer (score 1):

ざっと訳すると、

> We found your app provides potentially unauthorized access to third-party audio or video streaming.

「あなたのアプリが、権限の無い、サードパーティのAudio や Videoのストリーミングへの、潜在的なアクセスを提供する」ことを発見しました。

> Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of another party. In the event your app infringes another party’s rights, you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim.

「あなたのアプリと内容物は、他者の権利を侵害すべきではありません。もし、あなたのアプリが他者の権利を侵害した場合、あなたはクレイムによってApple社に生じたいかなる法的責任についての責任があります。」

> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App Review Information section in App Store Connect evidencing that you have all necessary rights or permissions to the third-party audio or video streaming, catalogs, and discovery services in your app.

「本件の解決のため、あなたがサードパーティのaudioやvideoのストリーミング、カタログ、等について、全ての権利もしくは許諾を持っていることを示す証拠となる文書を提示いただきたい」

---

英語が堪能で、ネットワークサービス等に関するアメリカの法律をよく知る知人が居るなら、相談するとよいです。
そういう知人が居ないのなら、ネットワーク上の情報やサービスの権利関係について詳しい米国の弁護士に相談するのが良いと思います。

年間の営業利益が５兆円を超える大企業であるApple社を相手に、質問に書かれている英語の文章の意味が判らない程度の英語力しかない質問者が独力で立ち向かうのは、無謀です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

基本的にサードパーティーライブラリを使用したYoutube動画のストリーミング再生（通常再生）はアプリでは不可能ということですね。

Comment: Youtubeの公式が認めてるので許可が降りてない動画は再生されないという旨の文章を送ったら審査通りました！